# Object detection: when there's only 1 object in each image

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, dataset, object-detection

Good day. I have a custom dataset for object detection, which has imbalance that **each image has only one object annotation**.

I trained the object detection model(Efficientdet-dx) on TensorFlow object detection API with this dataset. But the model predicts only one object in image, even though it has many trackable objects when the training has finished. It looks like the model learned in the wrong way that it should find only one object in a image.

[image: Sample trainset]

Here's my question: In which way should I train the model, so the model find objects independently to the number of objects in the trainset?

It should be very helpful, if you help me.

What I tried:

- [Copy and Paste augmentation(CAP)](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/simple-copy-paste-is-a-strong-data)

  - result: The dataset has no mask annotation unfortunately, so I used a deep learning model trained on open dataset for background subtraction, but the subtraction did not work well. As you can see, the edge of pasted objects is not clear. and some part of the objects are missing.

[image: CAP augmentation]

- Mix another dataset like COCO, PASCAL VOC.

  - result: It wasn't that bad such like CAP. However, the mixed dataset becomes very big size and the unrelated labels also are in the predictable label list.

Comment: try some other stack exchanges. see the note here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Thanks. I haven't had that much of experience posting on Stackoverflow. I just writed this post on https://ai.stackexchange.com/. @ChristophRackwitz